# Considering the following method:

Tags: java, methods, return

```java
public static int secret(int value) {
     int prod = 1;
     for(int i =1; i <= 3; i++) {
          prod = prod * value;
     }
     return prod;
}
```

What would be the output of:

```java
System.out.println("First secret call: " + secret(5));
System.out.println("Second secret call: " + (2 * secret(6)));
```

and what does the method *secret* do

Comment: why don't you write the program and find out?

Comment: Run it and see, it is basic math(almost) really.. :)

Comment: The first thing I did was attempt to run it, but it gave me a multitude of errors >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output would be 125 and then 432.  The method, "secret", cubes the number passed into it.

Comment: of course, Einstein the point is the person should learn on their own.

Comment: Is that the point?  I thought the point was to answer a question.

Comment: Not on such simple questions that show no effort whatsoever.

Comment: I see.  Well, I figured we all have different levels of intelligence.  What is a simple question for one person might not be simple for another. My bad.

Comment: Great point you provide in your comment @ChoppinBroccoli , seeing as I have practically zero knowledge of Java and its logic.

Comment: @dingles Did you learn anything anything by being fed the answer?

Comment: Yup, he learned ChoppinBroccoli is a nice guy that will give him answers :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes actually seeing the output of those println's and being told what the method is helped with my understanding of how this method works.  It helped me far more than a comment like "Why don't you run it and find out."  Yes, I obviously attempted to run it first.  If you more advanced  programmers with your vast knowledge would spend less time telling people their question is stupid and actually helping them understand, this site would be pretty great.  Too bad that is not the case :D

Comment: Thank you again @Choppin Broccoli , yes truly a nice guy!

Answer (score 0):

everything fits in a very small screenshot in two windows... try it, you will see it is fun, like playing lego but with more magic!!!

[image: left: the terminal to compile and run the program; right: the complete program code]